# Scala compiler error : only classes can have declared but undefined members

Tags: scala

Below class throws a compiler error at this line `val userList : List[User]` :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - only classes can have declared but undefined members
    - only classes can have declared but undefined members
```

Here is the entire code :

```
class SimilarityData {

  case class User(id: String, jCoeff : Int) 

  def getUsers() =
  {    
    val userList : List[User]
    userList :+ new User("1" , 1);    
  }

}
```

What is causing this error ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly `userList` is a `val` which means you need to initialize it. 
Secondly `userList` is of type `List[String]`. You cannot add `User` to it. This is how it should be:

```
val userList = List.empty[User]
userList :+ new User("1" , 1);
```

Comment: Why can't I use 'val userList : List[User] = _' ?

Comment: I should clarify that :+ is not modifying the existing list, it creates a new list and return it.

Answer (score 4):

You must provide an initial value for local `val`s:

> val userList = List(new User("1", 1))

The error is reminding you that:

- a `val` must have assigned an initial value, in your case as a local value in a method body.
- a `val` on an abstract class or trait may be left un-initialized - though it must be initialized by a (concrete) subclass somewhere along the line,